# javascript not loading in rails view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is my view partial _micropost.html.erb.

```
       <button type="button" class="answer-button">Respond</button>
        <section class="answer-form">
          <%= render 'shared/answer_form',micropost: micropost %>
        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(.answer-button).click(function(){
              $(.answer-form).slideDown();
            });
        });
        </script>
```

when i click on the button, the form should slide down. but its not working .

It was due tomissing double quotes in DOM  selector

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the `script` tag, it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

also, `$(.answer-button)` and `$(.answer-form)` are wrong, the class should be passed as a string, so basically it should look like `$('.answer-button')` and `$(.answer-form)`!

fix the typo then try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  $('body').on('click', '.answer-button', function(){
    $('.answer-form').slideDown();
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps!